# Getting rid of icloud on old iphone

Tags: icloud

Bought an iphone 6.  Set my old phone iphone 5 back to factory settings and gave to a young friend.  She keeps saying icloud is stopping her from using it. Took it back and did another factory reset via iTunes.  She went into mobile shop with it but she now says I need to give her my apple or icloud password or, go to 'find my phone' select 'all devices' to open list of devices linked to my account on the old phone. Not mobile savvy, too old to learn new tricks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Settings on iCloud.com, then look at the My Devices section.
2. In the list of devices, click the one you want to remove.
3. Click the Delete button (x) next to the device. If you don’t see the Delete button, click Remove Device (below the device serial number or IMEI number).

For full instructions please see here:
https://help.apple.com/icloud/#mm25565a6496

Comment: You are very welcome. If this answer took care of your issue can you mark it answered?

Comment: I told you I was old - how to I mark it answered?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers